# How do I generate unique transaction ID for payments or orders using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I generate unique transaction ID for payments or orders using PHP and MySQL, preventing duplicate IDs even on simultaneous large number of requests?

Although we can simply insert the data and fetch the `auto_increment` value using PHP `last_insert_id()` function. But will this be safe considering a large number of transactions would be running simultaneously?

Comment: Use an `auto_increment` column.  That is what it is there for.

Comment: How would you fetch the value after inserting the data? PHP's `last_insert_id()` function would do, but is it safe when many transactions are going on simultaneously?

Comment: `last_insert_id()` and `auto_increment` is the *safest* way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to generate a unique transactionId with date, and consider [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and concurrency.

First of all, `auto_increment` with `last_insert_id()` is a good way to implement.

Next, we could define a format for the transaction like `YYYYMMDD` with 8 digit serial which means the amount of record not exceeding 8 digits is created in one day.

Finally, we could use SQL TRANSACTION to write a procedure for implementation:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_date, amount) VALUES (NOW(), 100);

SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
SET @fixed_length = 8;
SET @last_digits = LPAD(SUBSTRING(CAST(@last_id AS CHAR), -LEAST(@fixed_length, LENGTH(CAST(@last_id AS CHAR)))), @fixed_length, '0');
SET @transaction_id = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'), @last_digits);

SET @transaction_id = CONCAT('TRX-', @transaction_id);

UPDATE transactions SET transaction_id = @transaction_id WHERE id = @last_id;

COMMIT;
```

The tips is to extract the last 8 digits from `auto_increment` with padding, and use it for the daily serial number.

Alternatively, SQL TRANSACTION can also choose to be separated to the Backend Server, then the SQL server won't do the function process.